# REP-110: file cannot be opened

Tags: oracle, weblogic11g, reportserver

I have the following error:

when try to run the report without full path.

> REP-110: File abc.rdf cannot be opened. 
>   REP-1070: An error occurred while opening or saving a document. 
>   REP-0110: File abc.rdf cannot be opened.

but with full path its ok.

Reports 11g is installed with weblogic server.

Comment: Where do you think it will try to open or save the file if you don't give a full path? What will it be saved relative to, and does the WebLogic/Reports process owner have permissions on that directory? (I'm not sure but I think there's a `REPORTS_PATH` environment variable to control this).

Comment: thanks dear, 'http://abc.com:9002/reports/rwservletserver=RptSvr_balder3_asinst_1&report=D:\project\abc_summary.rdf&userid=reptuser/reptuser@mcadb&destype=cache&desformat=html&paramform=yes' this is ok, but the following  'http://abc.com:9002/reports/rwservletserver=RptSvr_balder3_asinst_1&report=abc_summary.rdf&userid=reptuser/reptuser@mcadb&destype=cache&desformat=html&paramform=yes' without full path gives error.

Comment: I Think that your reports path is incorrect.At first you correct your reports path. Then it should be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that you added where the reports are in your registry editor in the following directory

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OH#########\REPORTS_PATH
```

Add

```
...ows\Fonts;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\reports
```